# Increment counter unavailable outside of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looping through json return values with jQuery's $.each() and adding the classes returned to their corresponding `<div>`'s; however the counter appears to be inaccessible for further processing outside of the immediate loop. I have tried using return's & external function calls to no avail. When I alert() the counter inside the iteration, it shows up correctly; and all of the classes update properly. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
var c = 0;
function refreshIt(){
  var page = $(".navselected").attr('id');
  var ids = $('.content div[id]').map(function(){
    return this.id;
  }).get();

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:page + 'functions.php',
    data:{'idList[]':ids},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
      $.each(data,function(element,load){
        $("#" + element).slideUp(400,function(){
          $("#" + element).removeClass("critical ok");
          $("#" + element).addClass(load.status).html(load.number).slideDown(400);
          if(load.status == 'ok'){
            c++;
          }
          else{
            c++;
          }
        });
      });

      $('.infostatus').addClass('infook').html("There are " + c  + " errors on this page.     Kudos!");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: its a scope issue.  that variable doesn't 'exist' anywhere other than the loop.  im not sure what to recommend bc i dont know much about what happens behind jQuery's $.each

Comment: @jon_darkstar: not true, the var is the first line of the script, outside of all code blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make that ajax call the browser sends the request and attaches the function to it, and then continues executing the rest of the script while it waits for a response.  This means that that last line of code is almost certainly executed before the ajax returns.  Put that line in the ajax success function, just after the each function:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:page + 'functions.php',
  data:{'idList[]':ids},
  dataType:'json',
  success:function(data){
    $.each(data,function(element,load){
    $("#" + element).slideUp(400,function(){
    $("#" + element).removeClass("critical ok");
    $("#" + element).addClass(load.status).html(load.number).slideDown(400);
    if(load.status == 'ok'){
      c++;
    }
    else{
      c++;
    }
  });

  $('.infostatus').addClass('infook')
  .html("There are " + c  + " errors on this page.     Kudos!");

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift response & corresponding explanation; much appreciated. Tested & verified.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to have rather more `{` brackets than `}` ones, so it's hard for be sure — but I'm guessing the problem is that you're calling `.ajax()` and then immediately filling in the HTML by calling `.html()`.

The `.ajax()` method only fires off the request; it doesn't wait until the response is received. So your `.html()` call is executing *before* the response comes back and the data is processed.

To fix this, simply move the last two lines of code into the `success` function, immediately after the call to `.each()`.

Comment: tthe brace-mismatch was my fault. My apologies, I missed a couple of in-side statements that had opening braces.

Comment: @Brad: Cool. The updated code in your question looks like it should work. It still doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

what is the purpose of

```
if(load.status == 'ok'){
  c++;
}
else{
  c++;
}
```

Here's your code, simplified:

```
var c = 0;
function refreshIt() {
    var page, ids;
    page = $(".navselected").attr('id');
    ids = $('.content div[id]').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:page + 'functions.php',
        data:{'idList[]':ids},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data,function(element,load){
                var elem = $("#" + element);
                elem.slideUp(400,function() {
                    elem.removeClass("critical ok");
                    elem.addClass(load.status).html(load.number).slideDown(400);
                    c++;
                });
            });
            $('.infostatus').addClass('infook')
                .html("There are " + c  + " errors on this page.     Kudos!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips on simplifying the code. After being unable to get if condition to work I tried various ways of getting any communication of the counter to go through; the extra if...else was residual and has been removed.